# What is currently the most comfortable and reliable cross-platform Perl module to do parallel downloads?

Tags: perl, cross-platform, download, parallel-processing

I'm going to have to download a number of datasets via simply POSTing at an url and getting XML in return. I will be able to speed this up by doing more than one request at a time, but here's the hook:

It will need to run on both Windows and Linux, so **threads and forks are both out**. (Since this is purely IO-bound i don't think they're needed either.)

Additionally my coworkers aren't on a very high level of perl understanding, but need to be able to grasp how to use it (not necessarily what's going on, usage is fine). As such i'd be happy if its **API was somewhat simple**.

Right now i'm looking at [IO::Lambda](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aLambda) for this.

Any other suggestions?

**Post-Mortem:** Based on draegtun's suggestion i've now thrown together this, which does the job perfectly: https://gist.github.com/661386 You might see it on CPAN soonish.

Comment: Why are threads and forks out? You can use `fork` (preferably with `Parallel::ForkManager`) on Windows with some caveats: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html

Comment: How, pray tell, do you intend to effect a parallel solution if you are forbidden from using either of forks or threads? Handling I/O muxing through a `select` mask is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Sinan: Threads don't work reliably under linux, especially not with older Perls. Forks do not work under Windows, period.
 ||| 
tchrist: IO::Lambda offers tools to do the select processing, but it appears to be broken with POST requests. I'm basically hoping someone uploaded a module to CPAN that can do that properly.

Comment: Threads may be dodgy, but I would absolutely never work in an environment where I couldn’t use fundamental multiprocessing techniques like `fork(2)`. Similarly if I were forced to use ancient Perls. Also, I am unaware of any problems for Prisoners of $Bill with forking on Perls built under Cygwin. Anything less than that is intolerable.

Comment: Let me put it like this: None of my coworkers has ever written a single test or even knows how to. I have an uphill battle. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`AnyEvent::HTTP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent-HTTP/).   According to the [CPAN testers platform matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=AnyEvent-HTTP+1.46) it does compile & work on Windows.

Below is a straightforward example of async POSTing (`http_post`).

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

my @urls = (
    [google => 'http://google.com', 'some body'],
    [yahoo  => 'http://yahoo.com' , 'any body' ],
);

for my $site (@urls) {
    my ($name, $url, $body) = @$site;
    $cv->begin; 
    http_post $url, $body => sub {
        my $xml = shift;
        do_something_with_this( $name, $xml );
        $cv->end;
    }
}

# wait till all finished
$cv->recv;
say "Finished";

sub do_something_with_this { say @_ }
```

NB. Remember whatever you decide todo with `do_something_with_this` try to avoid anything that *blocks*.  See other non-blocking [AnyEvent modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=anyevent%3A%3A%2a&mode=module)

/I3az/

Comment: Trying to apply this now. How would i POST with this?

Comment: `http_post $url, $body => sub { ... };`.  Have edited to show how to post *body* (NB. however my *body* is just example so its garbage data and not related to these sites).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfectly. Easiest way i found is to use HTTP::Request::Common to generate a POST request and process it with `http_post $req->uri->as_string, $req->content, sub {};`

Comment: Have you considered simply writing two parallel implementations, one for each architecture? `use Config; if ($Config{osname} eq 'linux') { ... } elsif { ... } ` ?

Comment: I thought about it for a second, but it would've been just more work, since a parallel downloader on Windows itself isn't easy in the first place in Perl.

Comment: Besides, i'm already well on my way to making a proper module of this. :) https://gist.github.com/661341

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [LWP::Parallel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP%3a%3aParallel).

#### Update:

I just tried to build it on Windows XP with ActiveState's 5.10.1 and encountered a bunch of test failures some which are due to the `TEST` script blindly prepending `..` to all entries in `@INC` and others seem to be due to a version mismatch with `LWP::Protocol::*` classes.

This is a concern. I might go with [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) in conjunction with [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Config::Std { def_sep => '=' };
use File::Slurp;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

die "No config file specified\n" unless @ARGV;
my ($ini) = @ARGV;

read_config $ini, my %config;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

my @urls = @{ $config{''}{url} };

for my $url ( @urls ) {
    $pm->start and next;
    my $param = [ %{ $config{$url} } ];
    my $request = POST $url, $param;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $fn = sprintf '%s-%s-%s.xml',
                     map $request->$_, qw( method uri content);
    $fn =~ s/\W+/_/g;
    my $response = $ua->request( $request );
    if ( $response->code == 200 ) {
        write_file $fn, \ $response->as_string;
    }
    else {
        warn $response->message, "\n";
    }
    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Here is a sample config file:

```
url = http://one.example.com/search
url = http://two.example.com/query
url = http://three.example.com/question

[http://one.example.com/search]
keyword = Perl
limit = 20

[http://two.example.com/query]
type = Who is
limit = 10

[http://three.example.com/question]
use = Perl
result = profit
```

#### Update:

If you need to convince yourself that execution is not serial, try the following short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(2);

for my $sub (1 .. 4) {
    $pm->start and next;
    for my $i ('a' .. 'd') {
        sleep rand 3;
        print "[$sub]: $i\n";
    }
    $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Output:

```
[1]: a
[1]: b
[2]: a
[1]: c
[1]: d
[2]: b
[3]: a
[3]: b
[3]: c
[2]: c
[3]: d
[2]: d
[4]: a
[4]: b
[4]: c
[4]: d
```

Regarding your comment about "reliability", I believe it's misguided. What you are doing is simulated by the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;
use YAML;

my @responses = parallel_run();

print Dump \@responses;

sub parallel_run {
    my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(2);
    my @responses;
    for my $sub (1 .. 4) {
        $pm->start and next;
        for my $i ('a' .. 'd') {
            sleep rand 3;
            push @responses, "[$sub]: $i";
        }
        $pm->finish;
    }
    $pm->wait_all_children;
    return @responses;
}
```

The output you get from that will be:

```
--- []
```

It is up to you to figure out why. That's why `Parallel::ForkManager` allows you to register callbacks. Just like the ones you are using with `AnyEvent::HTTP`.

What module you use is your own business. Just don't keep making blatantly false statements.

Comment: Have you tried actually running this under Windows? As far as i can tell, it only does serial processing.

Comment: @Mithaldu Of course I tried it on Windows. I do spend most of my time in Windows. See updated answer. I have basically done your job for you and the downvote is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok, you're right, it does run in parallel. I was thrown off by it being pretty slow in a real situation, where IO::Lambda can breeze through in a second. I'm also too used to people throwing untested code at me. I have to say though AnyEvent::HTTP seems to be the better solution just plain because it can work without needing an intermediary file. Also, since Anyevent::HTTP does the same thing in 20 MB, as opposed to 140.

Comment: What intermediary file do you need? The `ini` file was for separating code from data. If the requests can be hard-coded, feel free to ignore it. Also, you don't have to write output to a file ... feel free to register a callback as explained in the "Data structure retrieval" section of the docs.

Comment: I tried to avoid the write_file like this: https://gist.github.com/661144 It does not seem to work. Also, just in case you missed it: The memory use of Forkmanager is pretty horrendous. :/

Comment: Have you examined what `@responses` contains after the run? I think it is time for you to realize that the statement *"my coworkers aren't on a very high level of perl understanding"* needs to be revised. As I said, if you need data out of a subprocess, register a callback. Yes, `P:FM` might use more memory, but what you are doing does not help either.

Comment: Nah, i didn't look into that because my debugger does this if i try: https://gist.github.com/661144#file_gistfile2.txt (Remember how i mentioned reliability? ;) ) Meanwhile, this is simply perfect: https://gist.github.com/661177

Comment: I may have been wrong a few times here, but the moment a parallelization solutions starts throwing memory errors in my debugger, i step away from it. Plain and simple. The reliability issue is not because the obvious way to get things out didn't work, but because it threw memory errors.

Comment: You don't seem to realize that every forked process gets its own copy of `@responses` and pushes to that. I do not know what you tried to do in the debugger, but I believe the errors you got were related to that rather than anything that has to do with `P:FM` specifically.

Comment: I did not initially realize that, but i did after you told me to look at callbacks. And i did nothing special. I merely did what your last example shows and got those errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Mojo::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) can also do async paralell http. Its API might be easier to understand for non-perl people than some of the other modules..

Not sure if it qualifies as "reliable" yet ..